# Finding an exact substring in a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to find an exact substring in a string in Python. For example given the substring `"cat"`, the function should return `True` for the string `"abcatdg"` as it contains the letters of the substring in order, but return `False` for the string `"btacz"` as the letters of the substring are *not* in order. I've tried this code but can't seem to get it to work and I don't know why:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    if sub in string:
        return True #if sub is a subsequence of str otherwise False
```

If someone could point out to me where it is that I'm going wrong or what I'm missing, I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(is_subsequence("cat","abcatrat"))`

Comment: Your code should work fine if you fix your indention. You will need to add a line that returns false if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `False` if it isn't (otherwise it'll return `None`):

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    if sub in string:
        return True #if sub is a subsequence of str otherwise False
    return False
```

or even better:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    return sub in string
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, but you don't have a return for the `False` case. You should be able to simplify it to:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    return sub in string:
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works. Maybe wrong indentation?:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    if sub in string:
        return True  # if sub is a subsequence of str otherwise False
    return False


print(is_subsequence('cat', 'abcatdg'))
```

Although missing to return False in case the condition does not verify.

Answer (score 0):

Your function forgets to return `False` if the substring is not found.

The function you want already exists. It is called `str.__contains__`

```
>>> str.__contains__('abcatdg', 'cat')
>>> True
>>> str.__contains__('abctadg', 'cat')
>>> False
```

and is what is called when you use the `in` keyword.

```
>>> 'cat' in 'abcatdg'
>>> True
>>> 'cat' in 'abctadg'
>>> False
```

If you want your own function (possibly with reversed arguments), you can simply write it like this:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    return sub in string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's built-in `find` function:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    return string.find(sub) >= 0
```

Note that this returns the index of the first occurrence of `sub` or -1 if `sub` couldn't be found so I'm comparing it to 0 to see if it was found.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your indention and add an `else` statement for `False`:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    if sub in string:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_subsequence("bacon", "Makin bacon!"))
print(is_subsequence("turky", "Makin bacon!"))
```

Results:

```
True
False
```

If you would like to go an even shorter route you could simple return results of `sub in string`:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, string):
    return sub in string

print(is_subsequence("bacon", "Makin bacon!"))
print(is_subsequence("turky", "Makin bacon!"))
```